# Is it possible to display and edit the contents of a linked file?

Tags: files

In a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34099739/155423), another poster wants to write OpenGL shader programs *near* to where they are used. However, performance tuning indicates that you should compile these shaders once at the beginning of your program, which means you need access to the shaders in a non-local manner.

Would it be possible to have some indication to "inline" a view of another file? For example, say I had some raw source pseudocode like this:

```
// ~magic~ shader1.txt
fn my_awesome_method() {
    // do some things
}
```

When actually viewing this file, I would see the contents of the file `shader1.txt` instead of the comment. Ideally, I could even edit it in place, with modifications being written to the original file. In a way, it's kind of like a "live" `insert-file`, except it isn't modifying the containing file.

This way, the shader would actually be non-local, but you can view and edit it in the context that it will be run in.

Comment: Besides solving it within Emacs, you can solve it with a pre-processor.  A common kind of pre-processor which offers this kind of functionality are the literate programming tools such as `tangle`.